# how to move json file from a directory into another( cache directory)

Tags: java, android, json, parsing

I am trying to create a code that moves my json file( in assets directory) into cache directory, read the file and parse it. I already know how to parse it but I'm just not sure how to deal with cache directory. but I am not sure how to do it. I am new to android. any help would be appreciated. This is the code: In the middle of reading assets and parsing, I need to move the file into cache directory and read it there. How can I do that with code?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    List<String> questions = new ArrayList();
    // Reading json file from assets folder
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String temp="";
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("animals.json")));

        while ((temp = br.readLine()) != null)
            sb.append(temp);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            br.close(); // stop reading
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    TextView output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    String myjsonstring = sb.toString();
    String strJson="";
    String data = "";
    try {
        // Create the root JSONObject from the JSON string.
        JSONObject jsonRootObject = new JSONObject(myjsonstring);

        //Get the instance of JSONArray that contains JSONObjects
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonRootObject.getJSONArray("Employee");

        //Iterate the jsonArray and print the info of JSONObjects
        for(int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

            String text = jsonObject.optString("text").toString();
            String name = jsonObject.optString("name").toString();
            float salary = Float.parseFloat(jsonObject.optString("salary").toString());

            data += "Data"+i+" : \n text= "+ text +" \n Name= "+ name +" \n Salary= "+ salary +" \n ";
        }
       //String cacheDir = context.getCacheDir();
        readAllCachedText(getApplicationContext(),"animals.json");
        //FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(getCacheDir(), "cachefile"));
        //String yourFilePath = context.getFilesDir() + "/" + "animals.json";
        //File yourFile = new File( yourFilePath );
        //FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(getCacheDir(), "cachefile"));
        output.setText(data);
    } catch (JSONException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

Comment: So you only need move the file from the assest  folder to the cache folder

Comment: how do I do that? idk where the cache directory is. and for assets, what I did was getAssets() method. what is the code to read the file from cache directory. I am not sure how to do these 2 steps.

Comment: i don't understand you well. in your code you already get the json file and parse it. you want to move it from the assets directory to the app cache directory